# Error: Failed to load parser 'babel-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'babel-eslint' in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, babel-eslint

Trying to install [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) into [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app), but get next error when running linter:

[image: enter image description here]]

Here is my `.eslintrc` config file:

```js
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

If install `babel-eslint` manually it'll potentially produce another error based on package conflict between  project and `react-scripts` dependencies:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To fix this issue just reuse `babel-eslint` dependency from `react-scripts`, that already installed. Update your config:

```js
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parser": "react-scripts/node_modules/babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "config"? which file should be updated?

Comment: read question carefully: _.eslintrc config file_

Comment: Who is reading questions... I read only answers :) @AlexandrTovmach

Answer (score 24):

Did you install `@babel/eslint-parser` or `eslint-parser`?
In my case I had to use `@babel/eslint-parser` and `.eslintrc` looks like this:

```
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
```

Comment: As per the npm page of [https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint](`babel-eslint` ), it is deprecated. See this image on 

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/iqJ0FIm.png)

It says `babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser`. So using your suggestion worked for me. Thanks @Mahdiyeh

Comment: This helped me `https://tjaddison.com/blog/2021/03/updating-babel-eslint-to-babeleslint-parser-for-react-apps/`

Answer (score 6):

In my case solution was just run `npm install eslint --save-dev` for update eslint version

Comment: For yarn just `--dev`

Answer (score 3):

```
❯ yarn add -D babel-eslint 
yarn add v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
```

`babel-eslint` seems deprecated and package is now provided as an ES module under `babel`, so remove `babel-eslint` and instead install `@babel/eslint-parser`

```
yarn remove babel-eslint
yarn add -D @babel/eslint-parser
```

Answer (score 2):

`yarn add eslint --save-dev` solved that issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

A little late here but thought I would share what got me going...

I completely dismissed the error output which tells me where the `.eslintrc` file (that is looking for said package) lives. As you can see... I had some random `.eslintrc` living outside of my project which was somehow getting picked up.

```
Failed to load parser 'babel-eslint' declared in '../.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'babel-eslint'
```

##### Solution:

*Deleting this package ended up fixing the error for me. Not sure how that file got there but by mistake in a previous project.*

I suspect that it has something to do with installing babel-eslint and eslint globally.

Comment: remove eslint globally save me here

Answer (score 2):

For me, it is because that dependency is really not installed... I just followed the GatsbyJS's official guide, and it is not installed (not sure why that guide is not complete).

So just: `yarn add -D babel-eslint`

Answer (score 1):

I have yet another "this is what worked for me" answer. Like others my issue is definitely related to the deprecation of `babel-eslint`. My specific issue was that `eslint-config-react-app` was marked as a direct dependency, which I hadn't upgraded as part of upgrading a major version of `react-scripts`, somehow this left me with a version of `eslint-config-react-app` that was expecting `babel-eslint`, but only `@babel/eslint-parser` installed. For a while I thought the solution was removing the old `eslint-config-react-app`, but several iterations later I found I needed the direct dependency.

```
$npm ls eslint-config-react-app
client@0.1.1 /srv/
├── eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  └── eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1

$ npm i eslint-config-react-app

added 1 package, and audited 2909 packages in 6s

$ npm ls eslint-config-react-app
client@0.1.1 /srv/
├── eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  └── eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1 deduped
```

Answer (score 0):

Running eslint on your projects root folder `eslint .` will display the missing packages that you might need to install and that worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@babel/eslint-parser` in .eslintrc

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As for me i simply install this  npm install eslint@4.x babel-eslint@8 - g  and it works for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31671570)

Answer (score 0):

This works like Charm

> npm update eslint